# URL is display for popup windows in Windows10 with Edge browser

Tags: javascript, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am getting URL in popup windows on Windows10 with IE Edge.Could you please suggest how to hide this URL. I am using java script for popup and call the popup windows from html code.Same code is working fine on Windows7 with IE11.

Thanks & Regards ,
SPradhan[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La8zq.jpg)

Comment: please share the code, so that we can debug;

Comment: what is causing it? this is an impossible question. When you find out what javascript is doing it, remove that javascript ... solved

Comment: function test(){ 
myurl="PopupActionCall.do?popupCalled=yes&hidden=popupCityName&keyVal="+form.cityNameCode.value;
window.open('myurl',"test","width=500,height=500,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=1,fullscreen=no"); 
}

Comment: I called above test() from below html code

<table> 
<tr> 
<td>
<html:text name="bodyForm" style="<%=cityName%>" property="cityName" onfocus="this.select();" size="25" maxlength="20" onkeypress="return isAplhabetKey(event)" onchange="javascript:getTxtBoxValue('getCityNameValue');" onkeypress="javascript:enterCheck(event,'getCityNameValue');‌​"> 
</html:text> <a href="javascript:test();"> <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/myicon.gif" /></a> 
</td> 
</tr> 
<table>

I can see above url address on my popup window.